# Flurry Session data vs Google Analytics

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, metrics, flurry

We have Flurry and GA running on both Android and iOS apps. However, seeing 30% more sessions on Flurry than on GA for the same period of time.

Has anyone experienced this as well? Ideally don't want to run both.

Answer (score 1):

In Flurry, you notify the Flurry SDK every time one activity starts/stop.
If once the activity has been stopped, it is not started in more than 10 seconds, Flurry considers the new interaction as a new session.
http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ

In Google Analytics that time threshold seems to be 30 minutes.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en

This could explain the different number of sessions reported.

At the en of the day, what is a session in Android? Such concept does not exist. Analytics SDKs need to define the concept somehow, and if they use different criteria you will get different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed! The sessions at Google Analytics are 30 min by default, but you can manually change them to shorter sessions if you haven't. I would match the length of time on each session and then compare data after that. Good luck!